# Play Mp3 sound clip on mouseclick using jplayer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, mp3, jplayer

Actually this the first time I'm gonna use jplayer plugin, so all I need is to play a sound clip (2 sec) when I click on a div, and I don't know how to use jplayer!

I also need to load the sound clip file in cache as well as the page is loading, so when I click that div the sound clip plays immediately without loading it when clicking

btw, is it possible to do that without using jplayer, jquery maybe?!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to stick with jPlayer, try setting warningAlerts and errorAlerts to true.

`$(id).jPlayer( { warningAlerts: true, errorAlerts: true } );`

This may solve your problem.

But as long as you only need sound (no video), [SoundManager 2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/) might be a better fit for you. Its really robust and provides extensive debugging output.

```
soundManager.url = './swf/'; // directory where SM2 .SWFs live

var mySound;

soundManager.onready(function() {

    // SM2 has loaded - now you can create and play sounds!

    mySound = soundManager.createSound({
      id: 'someSound',
      url: '/path/to/some.mp3'
    });
});

//....
//if(xhr-stuff)
    if(mySound)
        mySound.play();
```

Use soundmanager2.js for testing and soundmanager2-nodebug-jsmin.js for production. If you have further questions, don't hesistate to ask.

Comment: Ended up using soundmanager2.js - thx a bunch.  Wish i could give you my 50 rep :(

Answer (score 2):

-snip-

scratch that... there's an api

http://www.jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-play

Use

```
$("#jpId").jPlayer("play");
```

Comment: This didn't work for me - I even tried adding $.jPlayer("play", 0); and it is still only playing one time.  Perhaps I should have just created my own question - but it was similar enough I figured i'd just offera  bounty on this one.

Comment: The following code preceeds my jPlayer('play') api call.

`$("#audio-player").jPlayer({
  swfPath: './aud',
  solution: "html, flash",
  muted: false,
  errorAlerts: false,
  warningAlerts: false,
  ready: function(e){
   $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
    mp3: "./aud/msg_rcvd.mp3",
    ogg: "./aud/msg_rcvd.ogg"
   })
  }
 });`

Comment: @Derek Adair You said you can only get it to play one time?  Are you trying to get it to loop then?

Comment: Nope, it's supposed to be triggered by via a custom event.  (I figured a click event was easy enough to substitute for my "custom" event).

Basically it looks like its TRYING to play again (it actually runs `$.jPlayer("play", 0)`) the audio appears to not be playing.

The only potential lead I have is it could have something to do with playing my OGG/MP3 OR something to do with headers or whatever.

Comment: That's very odd... I have never used the plugin before but I imagine it's on jplayer's end or the browser.  (does jplayer just provide a front end to the HTML5 player?).

Comment: If they do I don't wanna use it - I really just need a simple x-browser way to play a sound if the window is not focused and a condition is met in an XHR poll.